# Accessing all results of loop instead of last value

Tags: matlab

I have a for loop as follows:

```
for k=20:120;
    a1=(t1.*g)./(v1+t1.*k);
end
```

`t1` is a 5x8 matrix and using the for loop generates 101 5x8 matrices named `a1`.

In the command window, I can only access the last 5x8 matrix with `k=120`.

I want to access all 101 5x8 matrices.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're overwriting the previous matrix on every loop iteration. You need to store the resultant matrices in either a cell array or a 3-dimensional matrix. For instance, to store them in a cell array, you would do the following:

```
a1 = cell(1,101);
for k=20:120
    a1{k-19} = (t1.*g)./(v1+t1.*k); % subtract 19 so the index starts at 1
end
```

you could then access each of the resultant matrices using `a1{1}`, and so on

Comment: Whoops, sorry. Muscle memory in action. `i` is my go-to loop variable, which is a habit from other languages. Fixed.